# Como recibir un booleano de una API

Tags: angular

tengo un end point en un controller que me retorna un booleano y quiero recibirlo en un servicio en angular, debería recibirlo como un observable  o solo boolean?
Yo pude hacer esto pero no funciona:

```
  tieneAdjunto() : boolean {
      this.http
      .get(this.config.getConfig("host") + '/home/validate').map(
        res=>{
          console.log(1);
          if( res == 'true'){
            return true;
          } else{
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías imprimir "res", para saber cual es la respuesta que te da la API igual y la respuesta ya es booleano. Igual creo que tu if está un poco de más, podrías poner solo

```
return res;
```

Sí ya es un booleano

```
return res=='true';
```

si fuera una cadena de texto.